# Can I use with statements inside of for loops?

Tags: python, file-io, with-statement

I am trying to create a "file crawler" to go through my directories and search in the files for key words to return the directory. I have .txt files that has all the titles of the notes that I access with a with statement that I sequentially search with a for loop for the contents. My problem is that is is producing an error

here is an example of classes.txt, they are names of directories

```
Physics,GEology,
```

here is and example of notes.txt, they are names of .txt

```
ROck,other rock,
```

this is what you may find in a file

```
This is a rock and it is formed by silicon
```

if I type in 'silicon' for the key it generates and error

Here is the funtion, and I know it's a bit sloppy so bear with me.

```
def find_notes():

    print('enter key words you had in your notes')
    key = input('KEY> ')
    with open('classes.txt','r') as f:
        exist = False
        contents = f.read()
        contents = contents.split(',')
        for i in contents:
            os.chdir(i)
            with open('notes.txt', 'r') as notes: # save notes into a .txt in the working direcotry,,, Check
                class_notes = notes.read()
                class_notes = class_notes.split(',')
            for r in class_notes:
                notes_file = r + '.txt'
                print(notes_file)
                with open(notes_file, 'r') as stinkey:
                    real = stinkey.read()
                    if key in real:
                        file = os.getcwd()
                        file = file.split('\\')
                        exist = True
                        file_name = r + '.txt'
            reverse_dir()
        if exist == True:
            print('The notes are in:', file[-1] )# print the directory
            print('The title of the notes are ', file_name)
        else:
            print('Notes could not be found')
```

Comment: can you provide all files, that your program is using ?

Comment: if you print `class_notes`, I think you'll find some of the values in the list are an empty string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file referenced in this line

```
with open('notes.txt', 'r') as notes:
```

either has no content (empty string), or the text has two commas in a row. When that happens, this line:

```
class_notes = class_notes.split(',')
```

will assign an empty string "", which will be chained to .txt and cause the program to try to open a non existent file called ".txt"

Edit: replace the splitting line with:

```
class_notes = [x for x in class_notes.split(',') if x]
```

it will retain strings, pruning empty strings, None values and similar

Comment: whenever I write to my file it automatically appends a ',' at the end of my file. Is there anyway to resolve this. I can attach the function that is causing the problem if needed.